# Is data-reactroot relevant to the hydrate function in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-dom-server

I was trying to understand what's the difference between `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` and `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()` on React 16.8.6.

This is what I understood:

- `renderToStaticMarkup()` is used on the server side when you just want to render the markup and don't want to hydrate it on the client side. (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup)
- `renderToString()` is used on the server side when you want to use the `ReactDOM.hydrate()` function to hydrate the application on the client side. (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring)

So, if I'm right, the only difference between this two methods is that `renderToString()` adds the `data-reactroot` on the main element of the application. React reinforces this on the `renderToStaticMarkup()` documentation:

> Similar to renderToString, except this doesn’t create extra DOM
>   attributes that React uses internally, such as **data-reactroot**. This is
>   useful if you want to use React as a simple static page generator, as
>   stripping away the extra attributes can save some bytes.
>
> If you plan to use React on the client to make the markup interactive,
>   do not use this method. Instead, use **renderToString** on the server and
>   **ReactDOM.hydrate()** on the client.

But, I was reading [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12651) issue on React's repository where Dan Abramov said:

> Instead, use **hydrate()** to explicitly tell React to hydrate existing
>   HTML. **Then it won't depend on whether data-reactroot exists or not.**

And:

> ...The suggested migration path is to use **ReactDOM.hydrate()** which
>   **completely sidesteps the problem because it doesn't rely on the
>   data-reactroot attribute.**

So, my question is: **Is data-reactroot relevant to the hydrate function in React or is the documentation wrong?**

Understanding this will be really helpful to fix a bug I'm having while hydration.