# always use renderToStaticMarkup() over renderToString()?

Tags: reactjs

According to the react docs, [renderToString()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) creates extra DOM attributes that React uses internally such as data-reactroot whereas [renderToStaticMarkup](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) does not.

And I thought that `ReactDOM.hydrate()` enables event handlers to be attached to the markup which is string-rendered via `renderToString()`, thanks to that extra DOM attributes such as data-reactroot.

But I've tested myself that `ReactDOM.hydrate()` also works with the static markup which is rendered via `renderToStaticMarkup()`, which means that the combination of `ReactDOM.hydrate` and `renderToStaticMarkup()` successfully attaches event handlers to the string-rendered DOM.

According to the [Dan Abramov's issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12651), `hydrate()` does not rely on the internal react attribute (data-reactroot)

> Instead, use hydrate() to explicitly tell React to hydrate existing
> HTML. Then it won't depend on whether data-reactroot exists or not.

So I might guess that it would always be better to use `renderToStaticMarkup()` instead of `renderToString()`, since performance would be more optimized by `renderToStaticMarkup()`

Is that `ReactDOM.renderToString()` just an old way before hydrate() released on React v16, only to be used with `render()` and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML()`?

Is it okay for me to think that we can always use `renderToStaticMarkup()` over `renderToString()`?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57787670/is-data-reactroot-relevant-to-the-hydrate-function-in-react) is related to my issue, but yet has no clarified answer.

Comment: Have a look here https://lihautan.com/hydrating-text-content/